# XNA vector math movement

Tags: c#, xna, vectormath

I am making a top down 2D rpg game in c# xna for my game design class in college. I am attempting to create a simple AI that moves the enemy towards the player. currently my code is the following

```
    /// <summary>
    /// method to move the enemy
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="target">the position of the target</param>
    /// <returns>the new position to be moved to</returns>
    public virtual Vector2 move(Vector2 target)
    {
        Vector2 temp = (target - Position); // gets the difference between the target and position
        temp.Normalize();                   // sets the vector to unit vector
        temp *= moveSpeed;                  // sets the vector to be the length of moveSpeed
        float x = temp.X;
        float y = temp.Y;
        float xP, yP;
        double angle = Math.Acos(((x * direction.X) + (y * direction.Y)) / (temp.Length() * direction.Length())); //dot product finds the angle between temp and direction
        angle *= agility;                                                                                        //gets the angle to move based on agility
        xP = (float)(Math.Cos(angle) * (x - direction.X) - Math.Sin(angle) * (y - direction.Y) + x); 
        yP = (float)(Math.Sin(angle) * (x - direction.X) - Math.Cos(angle) * (y - direction.Y) + y);            // these lines rotate the point x,y around the direction vector by angle "angle"
        return new Vector2(xP, yP);
    }
```

the target is passed in correctly in the update method:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// updates the enemy
    /// </summary>
    public void update()
    {
        this.Position = move(Game1.player.Position);
    }
```

but the enemy doesn't move at all. I added code to the constructor making sure that agility and move speed were not 0. changing those values does nothing.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why not use the `Dot` method?

Comment: You can also use 'Math.Atan2((PlayerPosition.Y - EnemyPosition.Y), (PlayerPosition.X - EnemyPosition.Y));' to calculate the angle. I find it easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you return this (code for angle of direction):

```
xP = (float)(Math.Cos(angle) * (x - direction.X) - Math.Sin(angle) * (y - direction.Y) + x);  
yP = (float)(Math.Sin(angle) * (x - direction.X) - Math.Cos(angle) * (y - direction.Y) + y);            // these lines rotate the point x,y around the direction vector by angle "angle" 

return new Vector2(xP, yP);
```

But you need to return this for move:

```
temp *= moveSpeed;                  // sets the vector to be the length of moveSpeed    
float x = temp.X;    
float y = temp.Y; 
...

return new Vector2(x, y);
```